# how can you completely format the ssd disk and erase data in the MacBook - after cyberattack

Tags: macos, formatting, secure-erase

Unfortunately, I had a cyber attack that took control of my browser, running background processes on my laptop. I have already Erased All Contents and Settings with these steps:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click System Preferences in the menu bar > Erase All Contents and Settings

Can it be enough? Or do I need a more intensive formatting? In this case what could I do and how.
I have a MacBook Pro with T2 chip and Monterey.

Comment: According to Apple, that should be enough (from https://support.apple.com/HT212749): "macOS Monterey includes Erase All Content and Settings, a way to quickly and securely erase all of your settings, data, and apps, while maintaining the operating system currently installed. If your Mac includes this feature when using macOS Monterey, use it instead of other utilities to erase your Mac.". If you still feel that's not enough, you can erase the drive as explained here: https://support.apple.com/HT208496.

Comment: You're welcome, should I rewrite my comment into an answer so that you can accept it, or would you prefer to wait for others to chime in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple, erasing your Mac with System Preferences > Erase All Contents and Settings...:

[image]

should be enough (from https://support.apple.com/HT212749):

> macOS Monterey includes Erase All Content and Settings, a way to
> quickly and securely erase all of your settings, data, and apps, while
> maintaining the operating system currently installed. If your Mac
> includes this feature when using macOS Monterey, use it instead of
> other utilities to erase your Mac.

If you still feel that's not enough (or the option is not available because your Mac doesn't include an [Apple T2 Security Chip](https://support.apple.com/HT208862)), you can erase the drive as explained here:

- Intel Macs: https://support.apple.com/HT208496
- Apple Silicon Macs: https://support.apple.com/HT211814